# SDL mouse position with multiple sdl windows

Tags: c++, sdl, mouse

With these lines I managed to get the mouse coordinates only inside my sdl window. This code is inside the "draw" function.

```
SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_MOUSE_RELATIVE_MODE_WARP, "1", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);
SDL_GetMouseState(&mxx, &myy);
//other code
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Now I draw two windows: **there is a way to obtain mouse position only when it is inside the first window?** (when the mouse inside the second window consider it as out of border of the first window and coordinates are not updated)

```
void draw(){
  //common part
  if (windowId == 0) {
  //draw something in the first window
  }
  else {
  //draw other things in the second window
  } 
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

This is my draw function this structure, called in the main like this after creating 2 SDL windows object

```
window1.draw()
window2.draw()
```